# Testing a website with XAMPP

Tags: php, testing, xampp

I am trying to use a star rating system on my site, I'm using XAMPP as my testing server. Everything is working fine with the star rating system except for when I click on a star it's not sending my rating to my database. My question is, in this case since my site's not live yet and I'm just previewing it in the browser, would it even be possible for it to send that data to my database since it's not live? I'm new to this so please be kind. Thank you.

Comment: There is no reason why it wouldn't work on a local server - there's no fundamental difference between that and a site on the internet as long as you're talking to it via an address like `http://localhost`. So there's probably a bug somewhere. As a first step, check out the Javascript error console and the browser's "Net" tab where you see what requests have gone out - or not. With that info, you could edit your question (and post relevant parts of the code, too)

Comment: If you have XAMPP properly loaded and installed you should be able to get everything working. Beyond that it's anybody's guess what's going wrong. Do some debugging and post more information.

Comment: Where do I get to the browser's "Net" tab and the Javascript error console? Thank you. @Pekka웃

Comment: In Chrome - right-click, "Inspect element", then you get a row of tabs to the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. XAMPP have a local database that you can use when you are testing or developing in your environment.

You know that you are using this because in you code you are using something like:

$host = "localhost";

or

$host = "127.0.0.1";

You can use you remote database if you:

1. open the database port 3306 in the remote server firewall.
2. modify your my.cnf

you can see this tutorial.

[How Do I Enable Remote Access To MySQL Database Server?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Have fun :)